# Elasticsearch : How to retrieve empty fields associated with other conditions?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I'm trying to write a query to respect the following conditions:

`code` : equal to "my_code"
AND
`my_field` : is missing OR is empty ("")

I've tried the following, but I get a result with code `"my_code"` despite the fact that the `"my_field"` field is not empty.

```
{
  "from": 0, 
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "code": "my_code"
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "missing": {
                            "field": "my_field"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "exists": {
                            "field": "my_field"
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "term": {
                            "my_field": ""
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": "desc"
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't know where I went wrong but if anyone can help me it would be really helpful.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

```
 {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "match": {
              "code": "my_code"
            }
          },
          "must_not": [
            {
              "term": {
                "my_field": ""
              }
            },
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "my_field"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

This should work

Comment: This is working only if i have condition in code but when i only make condition in my_field the results are wrong